# Freerdp mouse cursor changes its shape to X on the margins

Tags: xfreerdp

I'm running `xfreerdp` on an arm64.  The package version is `2.0.0~git20190204.1.2693389a+dfsg1-2~bpo10+1`.

Sometimes when I run an `xfreerdp` instance and then move the mouse cursor to the margins of the screen (left/right/bottom), the cursor changes shape to `X` as in the attached picture.

Please explain why this happens, and how to avoid it?

[image]

Comment: It's called floatbar, and it seems that the way to disable it is -floatbar, but this option is not respected for some reason.

Comment: Odd that this is closed.  Last comment says the problem reappeared:  https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/4899